# Можно ли сделать кнопку, чтобы отсылала к группе, откуда пришло сообщение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Правильно ли я использовал кнопки `Inline`? Через них возможно настройку ссылки на группу, откуда было переслано сообщение? И как это можно сделать?

```
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
my_id = int('1047621278')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    print(message)


@bot.message_handler(regexp="ключевое слово")
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти по сообщению", callback_data="data1")
    keyboard.add(callback_button)
    bot.send_message(my_id, message.text, reply_markup=keyboard)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Не надо писать `int('1047621278')` можно же просто написать `1047621278`! Подучите Python

Comment: Сердечно благодарю, за комментарий! Спасибо Вам за моё просветление!

Comment: Простите, касательно вопроса есть какие-нибудь комментарии?

Comment: Можно просто ссылку на групу вписать. Или Вы не знаете из какой группы будет?

Comment: Не совсем понят вопрос, не могли бы уточнить?

Comment: Да, конечно! По данному коду мне везде, где бы я не добавлял бота (имею в виду группы), мне пересылается сообщение, содержащие ключевое слово. Так же указано от кого пришло сообщение, но нет информации из какого чата. Я придумал сделать кнопку под каждым присланным сообщением, в которой должна быть ссылка на группу. Но как конкретно это сделать - пока не понимаю.

Comment: Думаю Вам удобнее будет сделать так же как и от кого пришло сообщение, то есть сразу с какой групы, а не добавлять кнопки

Comment: Сейчас не очень понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду и как это сделать? Так как приходит ID человека, но не группы. И если человек зарегестрирован так же в нескольких группах - не понятно из какой группы он написал.

Comment: Сейчас дам ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов -

1. `print(message.chat.title)` - Для получения названия группы в чате
   `print(message.chat.username)` - Для получения ника группы (если он существует, иначе получите ошибку)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    print(message.chat.title)
    id_chata = message.chat.id    # Получаем id чата
    if 'ключевое слово' in message.text.lower():
```

2. `print(message.forward_from_chat.id)` - Для получения `id` чата из пересланого сообщения  (Использовать только когда бот Вам пересылает сообщение, иначе будет ошибка)
3. `print(message.forward_from_chat.title)` - Для получения названия группы (Использовать только когда бот Вам пересылает сообщение, иначе будет ошибка)
4. `print(message.forward_from_chat.username)` - Для получения юзернейма группы (Использовать только когда бот Вам пересылает сообщение, иначе будет ошибка)

Что бы сделать ссылку на канал -

```
chat_name = message.forward_from_chat.username
link_to_chat = 'https://t.me/' + chat_name
print(link_to_chat)
```

Вывод -
[`https://t.me/wwp_python`](https://t.me/wwp_python)

Comment: Дело в том, что чат id - это номер, и я пока не могу достичь названия группы, которая представлялась бы ссылкой.

Comment: Есть и другой способ) Сейчас отредактирую)

Comment: Да, вывести chat.id у меня получается, но я не знаю как из id: -1001118554477 сделать ссылку, или как просто переключить человека на группу из которой сообщение переслано. Проблема в том, что группа закрытая. Ещё я думаю, что ещё вариант был бы такой, чтобы в буфер скопировать текст сообщения, чтобы поиском в телеге человек сам смог воспользоваться. Но конечно удобнее было бы в один клик перейти к сообщению.

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите)

Comment: к сожалению, не работает, так как группа закрытая.

Comment: Первый вариант работает если бот находиться в группе

Comment: Не, так не получается, у чатов закрытых нет названия, как Вы указываете.

Comment: А юзернейм есть?

Comment: Нет, ну по крайней мере на просторах интернета я не увидел ничего такого. То есть благодаря ID чат открывается, но только в веб версии

Comment: К сожалению, вопрос так и остался открытым.

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

my_id = int('1047621278')
id_Alex='237937423'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    print(message)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id,message.from_user.id)
    id_chata = message.chat.id
    if 'ключевое слово' in message.text.lower():
        bot.forward_message(my_id, message.chat.id, message.id)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Копировать сообщение', switch_inline_query_current_chat=message.text)
        keyboard.add(callback_button)
        modul=abs(message.chat.id)
        if message.chat.title != None:
            bot.send_message(my_id, "[{}](https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=s{})".format(message.chat.title,modul), disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode="Markdown",reply_markup=keyboard)
            
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Вот так сделал через веб, но вылезает ошибка 
Method: channels.getParticipants Result: {"_":"rpc_error","error_code":400,"error_message":"CHANNEL_INVALID"}

Comment: Да зачем Вы строку в число переводите (`int('1047621278')`) если можно сразу число (`1047621278`) написать???